# Taxation on Freelancing Software Jobs in India

Tags: income-tax, india

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indian Citizen want to work as a freelancer for Europe. How to pay tax in India?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16467/indian-citizen-want-to-work-as-a-freelancer-for-europe-how-to-pay-tax-in-india)

I am an Indian Citizen and was working for a Canadian company while I was living in Canada. I have now decided to go back to India for good but I plan to continue to work for the same Canadian Company as a freelancer in India.

Do I need to register a firm in India for the same or can I simply invoice the company based on the number of hours I have worked and the company can deposit the amount directly to my Indian Savings account by wire transfer ?

I understand that for these earnings I would be liable for taxation in India only, please confirm the same.